# SQL Server Partitioning and Configuration Management

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I work in a team of developers and we currently manage our SQL Server database schema (tables, stored procedures, user defined types, etc) through TFS and Visual Studio using a database project. We keep our local development copies of the database in sync using the Schema Compare tools in Visual Studio.

I'm currently setting up partitioning on a couple of huge tables of data which has resulted in 500+ FileGroups & Files based partly on what data we want to be on SSDs vs. spinning HDDs.

My question is, does anyone have a suggestion or experience on how to manage the database schema in TFS such that each developer doesn't have to setup the 500+ FileGroups/Files on each development machine?

The reason I want to avoid this is because

1. On our development machines we will only have a small amount of data
   loaded based on disk space.
2. We plan to have a maintenance job on our production server to move data from SSD partitions to HDD partitions based on age. This means our production partitioning function won't match our development machines for very long anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, for your situation you can try to use **server workspace**. When you need to modify the files or projects, you just need to check out them.

> When you use a server workspace, Visual Studio keeps only one copy of
>   each file. This can **significantly reduce disk space usage** and
>   improve performance when you have a lot of items. We recommend that
>   you use a server workspace if:
>
> - **Your workspace contains more than 100,000 items.**
> - You want to use Visual Studio 2010 or earlier versions to work with    the workspace.
> - You need to use the Enable get latest on check-out option.

I'm not sure how did you handle the  a database project.  About how to put an existing database under source control, which consists of the following steps:

1. You create a database project.
2. You connect to an existing database.
3. You import the database schema from the existing database into the
   database project.
4. You review the results that are shown in the database project.
5. You put the database project and its contents under version control.

You can also use a **SSDT Database Project** For Your Data Warehouse. Below is an example of how you could structure your database project (am only showing a few tables and views in the screen shots for brevity). You don't have to structure it this way, but in this project it's sorted first by schema, then by object type (table, view, etc), then by object (table name and its DDL, etc).

[image]

More detail info please refer this blog:[Why You Should Use a SSDT Database Project For Your Data Warehouse](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2016/1/10/why-you-should-use-a-ssdt-database-project-for-your-data-warehouse)

Comment: I've already got a SSDT project setup in Visual Studio for my database. I'm trying to avoid checking in 500 additional file groups because I would prefer the other developers not be required to have them. I guess I could set the partition function to point to a single filegroup for development, check that in and always realize that production will be different.

Comment: Are you using server workspace? If so ,you may have to check in the 500 file groups in TFS server. However for the develops they don't have to  setup the 500+ FileGroups/Files on each development machine . They just need to check out the files they need and modify them then check in them.

Comment: No I'm not using a server workspace, but I guess my question wasn't clear. My biggest concern is that developer workstations really only need one partition because of disk space. And the partitions on the production server won't ever match because we are going to be modifying the partition function often to get our latest data on SSDs.

Comment: I'm thinking I just have to check it into configuration management one way and then manually manage the differences between configuration management and my production server for the partitioning function, files and file groups.